# How to retrieve the matching fuzzy term and its offset in solr and the payload?

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr-query-syntax, solr-search

**Part of the managed-schema.xml**

```xml
<field name="uid" type="plong" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="ingredients" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" termVectors="true" useDocValuesAsStored="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="false" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" omitPositions="true"/>

<field name="ingredients_mutations" type="ingredients_idx" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" useDocValuesAsStored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termPayloads="true" termOffsets="true" omitNorms="true"/>


<fieldType name="ingredients_idx" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
            <charFilter class="com.ourclass.solr.filter.OurReplaceFilterFactory" />
<!-- remove extra characters and tokenize values -->
            <tokenizer class="com.ourclass.solr.tokenizer.OurSplitTokenizerFactory" /> 
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="false" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<!-- generate string variations and put max token and number of the token that build a phrase into payload -->
<!-- apple banana orange will for example generate multiple termvector values and may like this orangebanana 2|3  orangebananaapple 3|3 apple 1|3-->
            <filter class="com.ourclass.filter.OurTokenFilterFactory" minTokenSize="1" maxTokenSize="4" addPayload="true" eliminateDuplicates="false"/>
            <filter class="solr.DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory" encoder="integer" delimiter="|"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
            <charFilter class="com.ourclass.solr.filter.OurReplaceFilterFactory" />
            <tokenizer class="com.ourclass.solr.tokenizer.OurSplitTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="false" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

**part of solrconfig.xml**

```xml
<processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="source"ingredientse</str>
    <str name="dest">ingredients_mutations</str>
</processor>
```

**Example Document**

```json
{
"uid":"juice_1",
“ingredients":["Apple","Avocado","Beetroot","Carrot","Lime","Cherry","Cranberry","Coconut water","Coconut milk",...] 
“ingredients_count”:[5]
“ingredients_mutations”: "apple | 1","avocado | 1","beetroot | 1","carrot | 1","lime | 1","cherry | 1","cranberry | 1","coconutwater | 1","coconutmilk | 1","appleavocado | 2","applebeetroot | 2","applecarrot | 2","applelime | 2","applecherry | 2","applecranberry | 2","applecoconutwater | 2","applecoconutmilk | 2","appleavocadobeetroot | 3","appleavocadocarrot | 3","appleavocadolime | 3","appleavocadocherry | 3","appleavocadocranberry | 3","appleavocadococonutwater | 3","appleavocadococonutmilk | 3","appleavocadobeetrootcarrot | 4","appleavocadobeetrootlime | 4","appleavocadobeetrootcherry | 4","appleavocadobeetrootcranberry | 4","appleavocadobeetrootcoconutwater | 4","appleavocadobeetrootcoconutmilk | 4","appleavocadobeetrootcarrotlime | 5","appleavocadobeetrootcarrotcherry | 5","appleavocadobeetrootcarrotcranberry | 5","appleavocadobeetrootcarrotcoconutwater | 5","appleavocadobeetrootcarrotcoconutmilk | 5“, ...
}
```

**Example query**

```
q={!frange l=90}mydist('ingredients_mutations','bananaapple'))
defType=lucene
q.op=AND
fq=(
{!cache=false cost=200}ingredients_mutations:'bananaapple' OR
{!cache=false cost=200}ingredients_mutations:'bananaapple~2')
start=0
rows=100
fl=*,score,mydist:mydist('ingredients_mutations','bananaapple')
sort=max(mydist('ingredients_mutations','bananaapple')) desc, id asc
```

**Example result**

```json
"uid":"juice_1",
…
```

I need the matched terms and the payload to calculate the score in my function.

How can I solve this?

Currently, I iterate through the mutations and calculate the distance using Levenstein. This takes too long.